go-redis: dial tcp: lookup i/o timeout
go-redis does not recover after being idle and I am not sure how to configure it to automatically reconnect and retry. When my service tries to execute a redis command after being idle, it fails the first time. However, subsequent attempts do work as expected.
Here is the error:
dial tcp: lookup z.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com: i/o timeout

Here is the line of code that fails:
r.SIsMember(context.TODO(), "x", x).Result()

And here is how I'm connecting:
    opt, err := redis.ParseURL("redis://x:y@z.us-east-1-4.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com:12719?dial_timeout=5&read_timeout=6s&max_retries=2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Err(err).Send()
    }

    opt.DialTimeout = 5 * time.Second
    opt.ReadTimeout = 3 * time.Second
    opt.WriteTimeout = 3 * time.Second
    opt.PoolTimeout = 6 * time.Second
    opt.MinRetryBackoff = 1 * time.Second
    opt.MaxRetryBackoff = 5 * time.Second
    opt.MaxRetries = 5

How can I recover from idle connections on the first try?

I don't remember there's a configuration for go to retry connection automatically, but you could set up a manual loop to check for i/o timeout error and if it encounters the error, it will attempt to create a new client to retry the redis operation until it reaches n number of attempts or the operation succeeds, whichever comes first
success := false
attempts := 0
const MaxAttempts = 5
r := redis.NewClient(opt)

for success != true && attempts < MaxAttempts {
    val, err := r.SIsMember(context.TODO(), "x", "x").Result()

    if err == nil {
        success = true
        fmt.Printf("SIsMember %t", val) 
        // Do something with val result
    } else if strings.Contains(fmt.Sprint(err), "i/o timeout") {
        attempts += 1
        r = redis.NewClient(opt)
    }
}


Does this mean that I have to check this before performing any redis operation? It seems very cumbersome that I'd need to wrap every call in this logic in go. Is this what most people do?

@poundifdef I don't use go a lot but from what I see most people do in java is to have wrapper class to wrap all the client API calls from a specific service like redis, aws to handle certain errors to avoid code repetition. So that whenever you need to make a client call, you can call through the wrapper object which will then help with error handling and keep track of client configuration should they need to be reconnected or retried

It looks like after your service becomes idle, all your Redis client pool connections are discarded by ConnMaxIdleTime (defaults to 30min), and when the pool tries to create a new connection it timeouts (DialTimeout).
Timeout errors when creating a new connection are not retried by the Redis Go client, so you get the error directly, and probably on the next try the connection succeeds faster.
You can try to increment your DialTimeout so the pool has a little bit more margin when trying to create a new connection.

I would discourage you from implementing the @vht981230 solution, since you'll be recreating the Redis connection pool on every retry (NewClient) and that may affect other concurrent requests causing a race condition. You should understand why a new connection from an idle state takes so long and adapt the DialTimeout accordingly (may be caused by some server cold start). As a last resort, you could retry the whole SIsMemberoperation after a timeout error (which already handles creating a new connection with the existing pool and is goroutine safe).
